# Nginx/Uwsgi log showing duplicate requests

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm running a flask application using nginx and uwsgi and I noticed when I tail the logs for uwsgi it looks like its just constantly polling my app when I'm doing nothing. It also seems like it's cycling through the cores on my machine with each request so I see this in the logs.

[pid: 27182|app: 0|req: 557/784] {26 vars in 254 bytes} [09:33:38 2015] GET / => generated 1337 bytes in 11 msecs ( 200) 3 headers in 238 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

[pid: 27182|app: 0|req: 558/785]{26 vars in 254 bytes} [09:33:42 2015] GET / => generated 1337 bytes in 11 msecs ( 200) 3 headers in 238 bytes (1 switches on core 1)

[pid: 27182|app: 0|req: 559/786] {26 vars in 254 bytes} [09:33:43 2015] GET / => generated 1337 bytes in 11 msecs ( 200) 3 headers in 238 bytes (1 switches on core 2)

[pid: 27182|app: 0|req: 560/787]  {26 vars in 254 bytes} [09:33:47 2015] GET / => generated 1337 bytes in 11 msecs ( 200) 3 headers in 238 bytes (1 switches on core 3)

Nginx shows something similar. It's just constantly issuing a request to my app.

It's only doing this when nginx is on. If I stop nginx the polling stops. My app is up and working but I don't know why this is happening. Is this normal behavior for nginx/uwsgi when using the uwsgi protocol?

**EDIT**  Im also using uwsgi in emperor mode

Comment: Is nginx doing healthchecks against application?

Comment: How can I check? Is this a setting or something?

Comment: @ThrowsException: What does the nginx log look like?

Comment: [09:57:52 -0500] "GET /" 200 1337 "-" "-" "-"<br/>

    [09:57:53 -0500] "GET /" 200 1337 "-" "-" "-"<br/>

    [09:57:57 -0500] "GET /" 200 1337 "-" "-" "-"<br/>

    [09:57:58 -0500] "GET /" 200 1337 "-" "-" "-"<br/>

    [09:58:02 -0500] "GET /" 200 1337 "-" "-" "-"<br/>


Also adding an edit to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry false alarm. This was my Devops incorrectly pinging my actual application route for heartbeat. Sorry for the confusion.